# How can we refine the "basic analysis" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Here's a great example of a question that generated several thoughtful and interesting answers in which advanced members of the community disagreed:

[How does one differentiate a song in Dorian vs. a song in Aeolian?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103708/2257)

It concerns a specific song, but the question actually has deep significance to the history of music theory and of classical music.

I suppose the "basic analysis" close reason is intended to filter out trivial questions such as "what key is Yesterday in?"  If that's the case then perhaps we should focus on the trivial nature of the question.  As someone once commented, it doesn't make sense for a music theory site to forbid questions on music theory.

It's also incredibly difficult to explain music theory without using examples of real music.  So here we have a close reason that basically says "we'll answer your abstract questions about theory, but you can't use a concrete example."  It doesn't make sense.

As of 28 Oct 2022, the close reason and closed post guidance read:

> **Basic analysis questions**, such as "What key is this song in?", are off topic. Questions should be substantial and refer to a well-defined work or subsection, including a concrete reference (sheet music, etc.).

Comment: Agreed. The close reason needs revision and clarification. Just know, the question mentioned in your post originally asked for the key/mode of the specific song, so was justifiably closed for the reason you mention. It was revised yesterday to focus on the more substantive issue.

Comment: @Aaron ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Proposed revision drafts

#### Close reason

> **Basic analysis questions**, such as "What key is this song in?" or "What is my voice type?", are off topic. Questions should be substantial, refer to a well-defined work or subsection, including a concrete reference other than a recording/video (sheet music, etc.), and have application or relevance beyond the specific work or musician involved.

#### Post guidance

> **Basic analysis questions**, such as "What key is this song in?" or "What is my voice type?", are off topic. Questions should be substantial, refer to a well-defined work or subsection, including a concrete reference other than a recording/video (sheet music, etc.), and have application or relevance beyond the specific work or musician involved.

> If this post has been inaccurately closed, consider revising to more clearly focus on the broader process, analytical issue, or general musical concern.

Comment: I would not lump "what is my voice type" in there. It's going to add to confusion as it's not related to analysis. I'm also going to point out that the question that cause this post was edited to the point where it does not reflect what the OP wanted and we really should not be doing that.